# ERROR: invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced while performing the left join in Postgres 11.0

Tags: postgresql, substring, common-table-expression

I have following table in postgres 11.0

```
atc_code_no code    level   text
1           A       1       ALIMENTARY TRACT AND METABOLISM
2           A01     2       STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS
3           A01A    3       STOMATOLOGICAL PREPARATIONS
3           A01W    3       (herbal stomatological remedies
4           A01AA   4       Caries prophylactic agents
5           A01AB   4       Antiinfectives and antiseptics for local oral treatment
7           A01AD   4       Other agents for local oral treatment
```

I have written following query with 'with' statements and then joining the tables using left join and substring match.

```
with level1 as(
        select CONCAT("code", ' (', lower("text"), ')') as atc_code_level1 from s0_atc_code
        where level = '1'
        ),
        
        level2 as(
        select CONCAT("code", ' (', lower("text"), ')') as atc_code_level2 from s0_atc_code
        where level = '2'
        ) ,
        
        level3 as(
        select CONCAT("code", ' (', lower("text"), ')') as atc_code_level3 from s0_atc_code
        where level = '3'
        ) ,
        
        level4 as(
        select CONCAT("code", ' (', lower("text"), ')') as atc_code_level4 from s0_atc_code
        where level = '4'
        )

       SELECT level1.*,
              level2.*,
              level3.*,
              level4.*
              
       FROM level1
       LEFT JOIN level2 ON btrim(SUBSTRING(level2.atc_code_level2, '(.*) \(')) ~ btrim(SUBSTRING(level1.atc_code_level1, '(.*) \('))
       LEFT JOIN level3 ON btrim(SUBSTRING(level3.atc_code_level3, '(.*) \(')) ~ btrim(SUBSTRING(level2.atc_code_level2, '(.*) \('))
       LEFT JOIN level4 ON btrim(SUBSTRING(level4.atc_code_level4, '(.*) \(')) ~ btrim(SUBSTRING(level3.atc_code_level3, '(.*) \('))
```

As long as, I am joining level1, level2, and level3, the query can join and provide me the output but when I join level4 and level3, I got an error:

[Code: 0, SQL State: 2201B]  ERROR: invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced

Following should be the output after the join.

I am having following table in Postgres 11.0

```
atc_code_level1                     atc_code_level2                     atc_code_level3                        atc_code_level4
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01A (stomatological preparations)  A01AD (other agents for local oral treatment)
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01A (herbal stomatological remedies)   A01AA (caries prophylactic agents)
A (alimentary tract and metabolism) A01 (stomatological preparations)   A01A (herbal stomatological remedies)   A01AB (antiinfectives and antiseptics for local oral treatment)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the error means regular-expression has a mistake,because this record:

> 3           A01W    3       (herbal stomatological remedies

has a left parenthese "(", when you use x ~ y, and y has only the left parenthese "(",so you get that exception.

**solution**:
maybe you can have a data clean to s0_atc_code before join:

```
update s0_atc_code set text = regexp_replace(text,'[()*]',' ','g')
```

delete "(", ")", "*" so that avoid regular-expression exception.